# Defining a Task Type in jBPM6 (in Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, jbpm

I use a simple Business Process with just Start->Task->End,
but after executing Test.java, which was successfully generated from my .bpmn file i become an error: "IllegalArgumentException:Cannot add asset...Task node[2] has no task type".

I suppose, i could resolve it by register my own custom task with .wid file. Unfortunately, after creating this file i cannot longer open my .bpmn file in eclipse.

Hope on your help.

Eclipse: Luna,
jbpm 6.3.0.Final,
bpmn-modeler:1.6

jUnitTest.java

```
package org.jbpm;
import com.sample.ItemHandler;
public class Hello_WorldJUnitTest extends JbpmJUnitTestCase {

@Test
public void test() {
    KieSession ksession = createKnowledgeSession("sample.bpmn");
    ksession.getWorkItemManager().registerWorkItemHandler("Task", new ItemHandler());
    ProcessInstance processInstance = ksession.startProcess("com.sample.bpmn.hello");

}
```

ItemHandler.java

```
    package com.sample;

public class ItemHandler implements WorkItemHandler {

@Override
public void abortWorkItem(WorkItem arg0, WorkItemManager arg1) {
    System.out.println("Work is aborted");
}

@Override
public void executeWorkItem(WorkItem arg0, WorkItemManager arg1) {
    System.out.println("You are welcome!");
    arg1.completeWorkItem(arg0.getId(), param);
}
```

Snippet from .bpmn source view

```
        <bpmn2:task id="Task_1" name="Task">
  <bpmn2:extensionElements>
    <tns:metaData name="elementname">
      <tns:metaValue><![CDATA[Task]]></tns:metaValue>
    </tns:metaData>
    <tns:onEntry-script scriptFormat="http://www.java.com/java">
      <tns:script>import org.drools.core.process.core.datatype.impl.type.StringDataType;
  </tns:script>
    </tns:onEntry-script>
  </bpmn2:extensionElements>
  <bpmn2:incoming>SequenceFlow_1</bpmn2:incoming>
  <bpmn2:outgoing>SequenceFlow_2</bpmn2:outgoing>
  <bpmn2:ioSpecification id="InputOutputSpecification_1">
    <bpmn2:inputSet id="_InputSet_2" name="Input Set 2"/>
    <bpmn2:outputSet id="OutputSet_1" name="Output Set 1"/>
  </bpmn2:ioSpecification>
</bpmn2:task>
```

Answer (score 0):

well it is saying that your task is Not Registered on BPMN file .change the first line of BPMN with .

- Copy bpmn source view code into Notepad and modified the BPMN code and save it as sample.bpmn and paste inside resources before that remove existing sample.bpmn file .

  ```
    <bpmn2:task id="Task_1" tns:taskName="Task" name="Task">
  ```

  i am sure it will work for any doubt ask here